# ros2 spinning problem[SOLVED]

Tags: ros, ros2, roscpp, rclcpp

i'm trying to transform ego-planner-swarm founded in:

https://github.com/ZJU-FAST-Lab/ego-planner-swarm

to ros2...

the problem was in one of the subscription's callbacks there was a function in which there was a "while loop" with only delay in it... and this loop's condition was dependent on other timers callbacks... and if the other timers callbacks wouldn't be called, the code would stuck in while loop. in ros1 to slove this kind of problem we can use

```
ros::spinOnce();
```

in the loop when the node is already spinning and that would prevent the code to stuck in the "while loop"
but in ros 2 if the the node is already spinning and you use

```
rclcpp::spin_some(node);
```

in the loop, you would get

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

> what():  Node has already been added to an executor.

that's because in ros2 when spin commands which get nodes as input argument are called, they automatically add node to an executor...

the second thing i tried was spinning the node using SingleThreadedExecutor and passed the Executor Instance to the while loop. then i used spin commands with using the Executor Instance in the "while loop"... things like:

```
Executor.spin();
Executor.spin_some();
Executor.sp_once();
```

this way i was not adding the node to an Executor... but i was trying to spin a node which is already spinning! and i got :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

> what():  spin_once() called while already spinning

then how i can fix this problem?

Comment: As @rubimat already answered: you add a node to an executor to spin it. 'Spinning a node' means that the executor waits for something to happen (receiving a message, service call, timer period lapsed, etc.) and then calls the corresponding callback. You **cannot** call `spin_once()` from a callback. If you want a better answer, you need to adapt your question to clarify _what functionality_ you want to achieve, and then we can write an answer on _how_ to best achieve that. But in its current form, the only answer is: "It is not possible.".

Comment: You have edited your question and placed the solution inside it. This is not how a Q&A site, such as Stack Exchange works. Please [edit] and remove the solution from your question and *post the solution as an answer* in the answer section below. Also, please remove the `SOLVED` from the title, Stack Exchange already has a mechanism for that, which is marking an answer as the accepted one. Finally, please take the [tour] to better understand how SE works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* that the functionality you are looking for, is the following:

A node that:

- Runs a blocking while loop in one of its callbacks,
- While at the same time also keeps responding to other events (such as receiving messages, changing paramters, etc).

You can do this by:

- Running the node in a multithreaded executor,
- Defining [callback groups](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html):

  - Either assign all callbacks to a Reentrant Callback group (if it's ok to run them concurrently), instead of the default (= MutuallyExclusive) callback group, or
  - Use (at least) two callback groups: one for the blocking callback and one (or multiple) for the other callbacks.

Callback groups work as follows:

- Callbacks belonging to **different** callback groups can be called **concurrently** (as long as there are available threads in the multithreaded executor),
- Callback groups belonging to **the same MutuallyExclusive** callback group are **not** called concurrently,
- Callback groups belonging to **the same Reentrant** callback group can be called **concurrently** (as long as there are available threads in the multithreaded executor).

Note that if you run a node with concurrent callbacks, you need to take thread safety into account. E.g. you cannot just write and read the same variables concurrently from different threads.

If this solves your issue, please upvote and accept. If it does not: refer to my comment: you will need to clarify you question as to *what functionality* exactly you try to achieve, rather than asking "how do I call `spin_some()` in a node that is already being spun".

Comment: thank you, this exactly what i wanted(callback groups)... the only thing that is different, is that the blocking while loop is not part of a callback

Comment: but i have to say the "loop while" is in a function which is called by one of the subscription's callback so i would say functionality you described is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

what solved it for me was Callback Groups in ros2 which user @JRTG introduced...(https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html)

now i will put my code and explain how Callback Groups Solved it.

```
using namespace ego_planner;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("ego_planner_node");

  EGOReplanFSM rebo_replan;
  
  rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
  rebo_replan.init(node);
  executor.add_node(node);
  executor.spin();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

here i make MultiThreadedExecutor Instance and spin the Node with it. i'm using MultiThreadedExecutor because in order to use Callback Groups Correctly one should use MultiThreadedExecutor based on the guide found in :
https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html

```
namespace ego_planner
{

  void EGOReplanFSM::init(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    auto target_callback_group = node->create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive);

    rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions options;
    options.callback_group = target_callback_group;
    waypoint_sub_ = node->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(
    "/move_base_simple/goal", 1,
    [this, node](const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped::SharedPtr msg) {
    waypointCallback(msg, node);}, options);
    .
    .
    .
  }//EGOReplanFSM::init

  void EGOReplanFSM::waypointCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped:EGOReplanFSM::init:SharedPtr &msg,rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    planNextWaypoint(end_wp,node);
  }//EGOReplanFSM::waypointCallback

void EGOReplanFSM::planNextWaypoint(const Eigen::Vector3d next_wp,rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node)
  {
      .
      .
      .
      while (rclcpp::ok() &&exec_state_ != EXEC_TRAJ)
          {
               rclcpp::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
          }
      .
      .
      .
  }//EGOReplanFSM::planNextWaypoint

}//ego_planner
```

in EGOReplanFSM::init function i have a subscription with the name of "/move_base_simple/goal"...this subscription's callback name is 'waypointCallback' and in it there is another function with the name of 'planNextWaypoint' and in this function lies the problematic "while loop":

```
while (rclcpp::ok() &&exec_state_ != EXEC_TRAJ)
        {
          rclcpp::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
```

by creating a callback group by the name of 'target_callback_group' and assigning "/move_base_simple/goal" Subscriber to it, i was able to solve this "while loop" deadlock... in this code i have two callback groups...
one is 'target_callback_group' and its for "/move_base_simple/goal" subscriber
and second is the node's default callback group for all the other callbacks...(when you don't specify a callback group, ros2 uses node's default callback group)
and both of these callback groups are MutuallyExclusive.

i tried to explain my problem and what solved it to the best of my abilities... i hope this help others as it helped me(sorry if my writing is not good, English is not my first language)

Answer (score 0):

The call `rclcpp::spin` creates an executor under the hood. The node can not be executed by two executors at the same time.

Equivalent to an `rclcpp::spin` call would be to add your node to and executor and spin the executor.

```cpp
rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;
executor.add_node(node);
executor.spin();
```

You could then use the same executor instance in your while loop. Note that a `spin` call is blocking. You might want to redesign your implementation a little by just using the while loop instead.

For more information about executors, please take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Executors.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer... i used executor.spin(); and then passed the executor instance to the while loop... but this time i get the "while already spinning"... i test with spin() and spin_once() and spin_some()

Comment: Could you update your question with your newest code, i.e. a liitle example so recreate the issue?

Comment: of course, i just updated my code... this time i used SingleThreadedExecutor to spin the code... but i get "node already spinning" when using executor.spin_once(); in the while loop

Comment: So you cannot have both, spin() and spin_once(). Either you spin it with spin() or your have your while loop woth spin_once()