# ROS2 multi-threaded executor timers block subscriber callbacks

Tags: ros2, rclcpp, multithreading

Using RCLCPP, ROS2-Iron, Ubuntu 22.04.

Using `rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor`

When defining callback groups, if I leave both timers and subscribers on the default callback group then subscriber callbacks won't be called until after a delay (10-20 seconds).

My timers and callbacks are accessing the same data, so I will have to use lock_guard's and mutex's to ensure thread-safety.

However, I don't want to put every subscriber and every timer in separate cb groups because of the development overhead to make each one thread-safe.

Why don't subscriber callbacks fire off like how they normally do when I'm using a `rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor`?

Answer (score 1):

The default callback group is MutuallyExclusive, so by just running a node in a MultiThreadedExecutor, the callbacks will still not be called concurrently. See [this previous answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107034/35117) for more info.

EDIT:

I adapted the [multithreaded_executor example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/rolling/rclcpp/executors/multithreaded_executor) so that the `DualThreadedNode` also has a timer in the same MutuallyExclusive callback group as its first subscriber. I don't see the behavior you describe.

````cpp
// Copyright 2020 Open Source Robotics Foundation, Inc.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

/**
 * A small convenience function for converting a thread ID to a string
 **/
std::string string_thread_id()
{
  auto hashed = std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());
  return std::to_string(hashed);
}

/* For this example, we will be creating a publishing node like the one in minimal_publisher.
 * We will have a single subscriber node running 2 threads. Each thread loops at different speeds, and
 * just repeats what it sees from the publisher to the screen.
 */

class PublisherNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  PublisherNode()
  : Node("PublisherNode"), count_(0)
  {
    publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10);
    auto timer_callback =
      [this]() -> void {
        auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();
        message.data = "Hello World! " + std::to_string(this->count_++);

        // Extract current thread
        auto curr_thread = string_thread_id();

        // Prep display message
        RCLCPP_INFO(
          this->get_logger(), "\n<<THREAD %s>> Publishing '%s'",
          curr_thread.c_str(), message.data.c_str());
        this->publisher_->publish(message);
      };
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, timer_callback);
  }

private:
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
  size_t count_;
};

class DualThreadedNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  DualThreadedNode()
  : Node("DualThreadedNode")
  {
    /* These define the callback groups
     * They don't really do much on their own, but they have to exist in order to
     * assign callbacks to them. They're also what the executor looks for when trying to run multiple threads
     */
    callback_group_subscriber1_ = this->create_callback_group(
      rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive);
    callback_group_subscriber2_ = this->create_callback_group(
      rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::MutuallyExclusive);

    // Each of these callback groups is basically a thread
    // Everything assigned to one of them gets bundled into the same thread
    auto sub1_opt = rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions();
    sub1_opt.callback_group = callback_group_subscriber1_;
    auto sub2_opt = rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions();
    sub2_opt.callback_group = callback_group_subscriber2_;

    subscription1_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "topic",
      rclcpp::QoS(10),
      // std::bind is sort of C++'s way of passing a function
      // If you're used to function-passing, skip these comments
      std::bind(
        &DualThreadedNode::subscriber1_cb,  // First parameter is a reference to the function
        this,                               // What the function should be bound to
        std::placeholders::_1),             // At this point we're not positive of all the
                                            // parameters being passed
                                            // So we just put a generic placeholder
                                            // into the binder
                                            // (since we know we need ONE parameter)
      sub1_opt);                  // This is where we set the callback group.
                                  // This subscription will run with callback group subscriber1

    subscription2_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
      "topic",
      rclcpp::QoS(10),
      std::bind(
        &DualThreadedNode::subscriber2_cb,
        this,
        std::placeholders::_1),
      sub2_opt);

    auto timer_callback =
      [this]() -> void {
        // Extract current thread
        auto curr_thread = string_thread_id();

        // Prep display message
        RCLCPP_INFO(
          this->get_logger(), "\nTimer callback: <<THREAD %s>>",
          curr_thread.c_str());
      };
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(100ms, timer_callback, callback_group_subscriber1_);
  }

private:
  /**
   * Simple function for generating a timestamp
   * Used for somewhat ineffectually demonstrating that the multithreading doesn't cripple performace
   */
  std::string timing_string()
  {
    rclcpp::Time time = this->now();
    return std::to_string(time.nanoseconds());
  }

  /**
   * Every time the Publisher publishes something, all subscribers to the topic get poked
   * This function gets called when Subscriber1 is poked (due to the std::bind we used when defining it)
   */
  void subscriber1_cb(const std_msgs::msg::String::ConstSharedPtr msg)
  {
    auto message_received_at = timing_string();

    // Extract current thread
    RCLCPP_INFO(
      this->get_logger(), "THREAD %s => Heard '%s' at %s",
      string_thread_id().c_str(), msg->data.c_str(), message_received_at.c_str());
  }

  /**
   * This function gets called when Subscriber2 is poked
   * Since it's running on a separate thread than Subscriber 1, it will run at (more-or-less) the same time!
   */
  void subscriber2_cb(const std_msgs::msg::String::ConstSharedPtr msg)
  {
    auto message_received_at = timing_string();

    // Prep display message
    RCLCPP_INFO(
      this->get_logger(), "THREAD %s => Heard '%s' at %s",
      string_thread_id().c_str(), msg->data.c_str(), message_received_at.c_str());
  }

  rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr callback_group_subscriber1_;
  rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr callback_group_subscriber2_;
  rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription1_;
  rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription2_;
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  // You MUST use the MultiThreadedExecutor to use, well, multiple threads
  rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor(rclcpp::ExecutorOptions(),3);
  auto pubnode = std::make_shared<PublisherNode>();
  auto subnode = std::make_shared<DualThreadedNode>();  // This contains BOTH subscriber callbacks.
                                                        // They will still run on different threads
                                                        // One Node. Two callbacks. Two Threads
  executor.add_node(pubnode);
  executor.add_node(subnode);
  executor.spin();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Reentrant / mutually exclusive refers to running the same callback concurrently, it doesn't refer to running multiple different callbacks consecutively.

"For the interaction of different callbacks with each other:
    Register them to the same Mutually Exclusive Callback Group if they should never be executed in parallel. An example case could be that the callbacks are accessing shared critical and non-thread-safe resources."

this means my behavior is still unexpected and a bug. My timer and cb's should take turns running, but they don't.

Comment: No. All callbacks belonging to a reentrant CBG can be called concurrently. Callbacks belonging to different CBG's (irrespective of reentrant or ME) can also be called concurrently. Callbacks belonging to the same ME CBG will never be called concurrently. If you experience differently, post a minimal code example showing this behaviour.

Comment: Of course what you said is true, but that's not the issue I have described. One would expect the same exact behavior in these two situations: 1. single-threaded executor. 2. multi-threaded executor with all cb's and timers on the same default cb group.  
My issue is that in #2, my subscriber cb's get called far slower than in case #1

Comment: Same remark holds: provide a minimal code example that shows the behavior. I edited my answer with a counter example.