# Multiple subscriber cbs to service handler

Tags: ros2, multithreading

I need to covert single incoming messages from a GUI (following the logic publish once) and in the callback invoke a service request to a device. The service request should wait for a response, which leads me to `rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete()` but this results in conflicts when running `rclcpp::spin(node)` in the Main.

I'm now asking for an example on how to resolve this issue (multithreaded executor/multithreading??)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this previous answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107034/35117) explains what you want to achieve.

See also [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107041/ros2-multi-threaded-executor-timers-block-subscriber-callbacks/107043#107043) for another example.